# Merge current commits of broken git repo into (old) fixed repo

Tags: git, svn, merge, corruption

I am working on a project which has a central SVN repository. I chose Git to work on local tasks via `git svn rebase` and `git svn dcommit`. Recently, I realized my local Git repo was damaged - possibly due to harddisk failures. Unfortunately, all my backups show the same errors: the history is cut off before Oct 26, 2014. The current checkout seems undamaged, however.

```
$ git log
....
commit cfccebf2d...
Author: jens
Date:   Sun Oct 26 21:37:01 2014 +0000

Add profiling support

git-svn-id: svn+ssh://IP/srv/.../trunk@5800 fa8e1804-...
error: Could not read b2f50c7c1...
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit 01cec01c....
```

`git fsck` shows a lot of errors too:

```
warning in tree ae1b5217e8f9713566b5867d9fe2986af4c8c2c6: contains zero-padded file modes
warning in tree c5ce65312b1cd4d84a78f30766a21308a9d12ea1: contains zero-padded file modes
warning in tree 538e6404bd24c40ac286e6e4614db3056c3774b6: contains zero-padded file modes
warning in tree 01eb58ab73e154e2b094d3a9c2f06742c1ca9b57: contains zero-padded file modes
Prüfe Objekte: 100% (82279/82279), Fertig.
broken link from    tree 258a66eaae794a83abee061fa52e87b8d9523a84
              to    tree b2aad577c42142cb3d26f498b346ea8ee2fa0b4b
dangling blob 7c095801143f844f6ff02484cd357a67e41f2b99
dangling blob 4112e0570791275836c68638846c7239e8dc22a4
dangling commit a41b40b6b9c39d79f5a7fb83aceca5891ec4eeae
```

... and about 40 more dangling blobs and commits.

Does it make sense to try and repair this repo by viewing and reattaching the dangling bits? Or should I rather create the branches on the SVN server, `dcommit` everything and then clone again?

Or I can also reclone the SVN repo (`git svn clone svn+ssh://IP/...`) and then copy all my local changes which were not yet `dcommit`ted to the SVN server to the new repo. This includes about ten old branches and two new ones with a lot of commits. If there a clean way to sync one Git repository with another starting from a specific commit apart from exporting all branches as series of patch files and manually doing a patch + commit loop, this might be the best solution (right?).

What is the best way to repair my git repository? I am using Git 2.5.1 on OS X Yosemite.